# Count permutation of an Array

Tags: algorithm, permutation

Suppose we have an array of length z. Which consists of x different even numbers and y different odd numbers.

So z = x+y.

We also know that x => 1 always applies.

1st question: How many different arrays of length z there are. That should be exactly z! many or?

2nd question: How many different arrays are there so that the last even number in the array is on an odd index. (The array in this example starts with index 1)

Examples:

1) [1,2,3,4,5] This array has length 5. The last even number in the array is 4 and has index 4 in the array, so we don't count such an array.

2) [52,3,14]. The last even number in this array is 14 and has index 3. So such an array counts towards it.

3) [52,3,5,7]. The last even number in this array is 52 and has index 1. So such an array counts towards it.

I simply don't find a good approach to this problem. In particular, I would be interested in a solution with dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:
There are z! arrays unless there are numbers in the array that repeat. The formula is the following:
n!/((n1!)*(n2!)*(n3!)*...*(nz!)), where n1 is the number of times the first number in the array repeats, n2 the number of times the second number repeats .. etc.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second question, we need to look only at the permutations of even/odd sequences:

```
eee…eeeooo…ooo
`--,--´`--,--´
   x      y
```

The number of these where the last `e` is in an odd position would then only need to be multiplied with the number of permutations amongst the even numbers (`x!`) and the number of permutations amongst the odd numbers.

So now lets enumerate the `e`/`o` permutations:

```
???????eooo…ooo
`--,--´ `--,--´
  i-1     z-i
```

For some `i` as the index of the last even number, there are many numbers that begin with a sequence of `i-1` digits consisting of `x-1` even and `y - (z-i)` = `i-x` odd numbers. You should be able the `i`s in a loop, check whether `x-1 >= 0 && i-x >= 0 && i-x <= y` (valid at all) and whether `i` is odd, then sum for each of those

```
(i-1)! / (x-1)! / (i-x)!
```